# Is it possible to use the success object from an AJAX call and pass it to thymeleaf to iterate over

Tags: java, ajax, rest, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Okay so I am new at Spring and ThymeLeaf and I am trying to learn how to use it so please be kind.

So I have a REST service that is returning  a list of objects.
I have an ajax call that is making a query to my REST service and passing back the objects desired as a parsed JSON via Jackson.
I want to iterate though list of objects obtained via AJAX call to REST service within a Thymeleaf iterator to get the data of each object of the list.

From what I know this idea of iterating through a list of object can only be done via a controller where you set the context and you pass it the list of objects and a key to iterate over in a web page.

And so my questions are:

1. Is this possible?
2. If so, can you point me in the right direction on how to do this?

```js
< script >
  function getAllByUser() {

    $.ajax({
      type: "get",

      url: "https://localhost:8443/api/getAllForUser",
      cache: false,
      data: 'user=' + $("#userAcctName").val(),
      success: function(response) {
        alert(response);

        //some how pass this response data to ${postsList}

       // $('#test').html("" + response[0].subject);

        $(".card").children().removeClass('hidden');
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('Error while request..');
      }
    });
  }

function getText() {

  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "https://localhost:8443/api/create",
    cache: false,
    data: $("#postSubmit").serialize(),
    success: function(response) {
      $('#result').html("");

      $('#title').html("" + response.subject);
      $('#dateTime').html("" + response.created);
      $('#data').html("" + response.content);
      $('#location').html("" + response.city);

      $(".bg-success").children().removeClass('hidden');
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
      //alert('Success..');
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('Error while request..');
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  //    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
  $(".bg-success").children().addClass('hidden');

}); < /script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head lang="en">

  <title>Spring Ajax</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />


  <link href="../static/css/bootstrap.css" th:href="@{css/bootstrap.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />

  <link href="../static/css/bootstrap-theme.css" th:href="@{css/bootstrap-theme.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />


  <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/jquery-2.2.2.js" th:src="@{js/jquery-2.2.2.js}"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/tether.js" th:src="@{js/tether.js}"></script>



  <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/bootstrap.js" th:src="@{js/bootstrap.js}"></script>



</head>

<body>



  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <!--         <img src="../static/images/FBcover1200x628.png" width="1000" -->
      <!--              th:src="@{images/FBcover1200x628.png}"/> -->
      <h1>Form</h1>
      <form name="postForm" method="post" id="postSubmit">

        <p>
          Username
          <input type="text" id="userAcctName" name="userAcctName" value="Default User" />
        </p>
        <p>
          City
          <input type="text" id="city" name="city" value="Default City" />
        </p>
        <p>
          Post Content
          <input type="text" id="content" name="content" value="Default Content" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="button" value="Done" onclick="getText()" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="button" value="Get All By User" onclick="getAllByUser()" />
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>

    <!-- Results block -->

    <div class="card bg-success">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title" id="title"></h4>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted" id="dateTime"></h6>
      </div>

      <div class="card-block">
        <p class="card-text" id="data"></p>
        <a href="#" class="card-link"></a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">See Popover
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer text-muted" id="location"></div>
    </div>



  </div>

  <div>

    <th:block th:each="post : ${postsList}">


      <div class="card ">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title" id="test" th:text="${post.subject}">Subject</h4>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted" th:text="${post.created">Date
      Created</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="card-block">
          <p class="card-text" th:text="${post.content}">Post Data</p>
          <a href="#" class="card-link"></a>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="th:text='${post.city}'">See Popover</button>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted" th:text="${post.temperature}"></div>
      </div>

    </th:block>



  </div>




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is No. You are trying to run Thymeleaf in browser but, Thymeleaf code is processed in server when the controller returns a Thymeleaf page. Once the response is generated by server and, there is no Thymeleaf (or JSP), everything will be translated to pure HTML.

You have two options here.

1. Move the Thymeleaf iteration to a separate Thymeleaf file. Then you can create a new Controller method that will return this template. Then you can do the ajax request to that endpoint. Now, say your controller will add a collection to the model object and return the Thymeleaf file as view. Now, your Thymeleaf file will be processed by Thymeleaf engine and will do the loop over the collection and generate an HTML that will be sent in response to the ajax call. Your ajax success callback can take this piece of HTML and put in the DOM wherever you want.
2. You can use the existing REST endpoint, get the response using AJAX. Then you have to write javascript to generate the HTML. But that would be tedious if you try to do it manually, but this can be done easily with some libraries (like Angular). But using both server side templating (like Thymeleaf) and client side templating (like Angular) is not a good idea IMHO.

### Update

Clarification on Option 1
You will create a new Thymeleaf file (normal file, not Thymeleaf Layout). Move the iteration code to that file (no need of head/body/title etc.). The idea is to return a partial HTML using a new controller method. This controller method will return the newly generated Thyemelef file in modelAndView. Then spring will evaluate the thymeleaf and create an HTML based on relevant objects that you put in modelMap. This HTML is accepted as a response in AJAX request and is inserted in to the document.

Also in the controller method, you can directly access the services/dao to get the data required, similar to way as the existing REST endpoint gets the required data. I haven't tried getting data from a different controller endpoint, but in theory that is also possible (again will depend on how the existing REST endpoint is coded).

Comment: Thought so, thanks for confirming it. If I were to go through option 1,can you clarify by what you mean by separating the iteration into a separate file. Are you talking about Thymeleaf Layouts? For the new controller, I am assuming you want me to access the rest service within the controller then get the list of objects and return the Thymeleaf partial view with the list of objects via Model View? Did I understand you correctly or did you mean something else?

Comment: Can you just clarify how I should go about doing option 1? thanks